# Wait for a sound to end playing. Is this correct?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

In my application I need to play a sound in different moments and wait for it to end before doing anything else. Right now I have this code for playing sound:

```
private MediaPlayer mPlayer = null;
private boolean playSound(){
    mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try{
        mPlayer.setDataSource(openFileInput(fileName).getFD());
        mPlayer.prepare();
        mPlayer.start();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("player", "error playing sound: "+fileName);
        return false;
    }

    while(mPlayer.isPlaying());
    mPlayer.release();
    mPlayer = null;
    return true;
}
```

It's not working as I expected: when changing an image before playing the sound the change happens after the sound is played (I suppose it's for the thread queue or something like this)

I don't know if this is a bad solution or if there is any better solution for my case:

- the sound playing must start after all previous work is finished.
- the app must not do any other work while playing the sound.
- the code to execute after the sound playing is not always the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement a completion listener:

```
public class myclass extends ....  implements OnCompletionListener, ... {

private int nextAction; // not the smatest solution, but good enough :)
    ...
    private boolean playSound(next){
        nextAction = next;
        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try{
            mPlayer.setDataSource(openFileInput(fileName).getFD());
            mPlayer.prepare();
            mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            mPlayer.start();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("player", "error playing sound: "+fileName);
            return false;
        }
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
      // do your stuff, destroy the mplayer, if needed
       switch(nextAction){
         case ACTION1: ...; break;
         case ACTION2: ...; break; //..and so on
       }
    }
```

Comment: But the code to be executed next is not allways the same. How do I solve this, using a macro switch and global variables?

Comment: that really depends on the logic you're trying to implement but you could always use some int value to determine your application state and act accordingly. see my edit.

Comment: Thanks, any idea of how to start playing the sound when all visual changes are completed?

Comment: what do you mean by "visual changes"?

Comment: For example, changing an image on an imageView, even though the code that makes the change is placed before the code that plays the sound it happens later. I just figured this out using a handler and putting this sort of things in queue and it seems to work great right now